# Quickly visualizing a large, binary matrix?

Tags: matrix, bitmap, ascii, plot, gnuplot

I'm looking for a simple, and especially **fast** possibility to convert a binary matrix (consisting only of 0 and 1) stored in a text file to some kind of a plot. A black and white bitmap would completely serve my purpose of visualization. I tried with gnuplot, but I think for the first time gnuplot doesn't suffice, as I have a lot of data (dozens of MiB, at least) and the memory consumption and processing time is awful.

When searching for solutions I mostly found stuff related to matrices stored binary (data format) and the possibilities to read a binary data format in e.g. gnuplot.

Do you know of any programs that can convert a text-matrix to a bitmap **fast**? I'm even thinking about writing a little C program doing that, but as I can't estimate how hard it is to create bitmap that way as I've never done image processing stuff before it would be nice to use existing tools, if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use netpbm. E.g.:

```
$ cat | pnmtopng > circle.png
P1 
10 10
0001111000
0111111110
0111111110
1111111111
1111111111
1111111111
1111111111
0111111110
0111111110
0001111000
$ file circle.png 
circle.png: PNG image, 10 x 10, 1-bit grayscale, non-interlaced
```

Here is the end-result: [image]

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly was I was looking for. I *knew* there would be a suitable UNIX CLI tool, it's just hard to find if one doesn't know what to look for ;-)

Comment: @user279714: Yeah, "netpbm" isn't exactly the first thing that comes to mind, eh? BTW, it took me forever to find the online list of man pages, which turns out to be a surreptiously-placed link on the main doc page to http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/directory.html.

Answer (score 0):

The only image output through C that I've worked with is the C JPG library, which may or may not suit your needs. It's not the fastest thing in the world, but it's easy to work with, and there are a few shortcuts you can do in the logic itself to make it a bit faster.

The way I'm thinking of is literally iterating through your matrix and outputting a black or white pixel based on your matrix value; I'm just completely unsure as to whether or not it will be faster or more efficient than gnuplot.